# Share Session between 2 Java EE applications deployed in JBoss AS

Tags: java, .net, session, jakarta-ee

I have 2 Java EE applications which need to share some common user related data of a logged in user.

Is there anyway by which I can store this data in the session from one application and retrieve that data in a second application? I.e. something similar to sticky sessions in .NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two separate Java EE applications will be having separate session data. 
If they are on the same domain and you want to share couple of attributes, then you could use a cookie and set attributes into the cookie and read them in each web app.

Comment: Thanks..Even though probably not the best of practices, i guess this is worth a try than the proved SSO style..cheers mate :)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at Single Sign On functionality.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_single_sign-on_implementations

Comment: SSO is th best option i agree.. But then i was actually searching for some work around for the time being. +1 for SSO but.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Single sign-on is the way to go (as prescribed). OpenId http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID (Providers include Google, Yahoo, MSN etc) is worth a look